# How to create phone format input in HTML if it's possible with country code

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core

I need a phone format input with a country code if it's possible i've tried few things but it didn't work so well  this is my code

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="@localizer["MobilePhone"]" id="inpMobilePhone" name="MobilePhone"  required />
    @*<label asp-for="ERPId" class="control-label col-form-label-sm">@localizer["ERPId"]</label>*@
    @*<input asp-for="ERPId" class="form-control form-control-sm" />*@
    @*<span asp-validation-for="ERPId" class="text-danger"></span>*@
</div>
```

Comment: Which things have you tried? What didn't work with them?

Comment: I've tried style="tel" and pattern="some numbers" but numbers past 11 char. and i couldn't see how to put country code.I am trying to do something like this (Country code) (555) 555 55 55

Comment: You can try to use jQuery mask plugin, where you will define your wanted format: [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use  `intl-tel-input`, a "JavaScript plugin for entering and validating international telephone numbers". Read  [this document](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) to know more.

Below is an example, you can refer to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>International telephone input</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <link
     rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"
   />
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
 </body>
  <script>
   const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#phone");
   const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
     utilsScript:
       "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this w3school post where it is explained. But it's won't be supported in all browsers.

[https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_tel.asp#:~:text=The%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22tel,tag%20for%20best%20accessibility%20practices!](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_tel.asp#:%7E:text=The%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22tel,tag%20for%20best%20accessibility%20practices!)

Basically it uses the type "tel" with a pattern to do the usual phone format (444-353-56-33).